# For $g_1,g_2$ in finite abelian group with $g_1\neq g_2$, there is $\phi\in\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb C^\times)$ such that $\phi(g_1)\ne\phi(g_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am having trouble with the following problem, taken from Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* 2nd Edition:

> If $G$ is an abelian group, let $\hat G$ be the set of all homomorphisms of $G$
> into the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication.
> If, $\phi_1,\phi_2\in \hat G$, define $\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2$ by $\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2(g) = \phi_1(g) \phi_2 (g)$ for all $g \in G.$
>
> Show that, given $G$ is also finite and $g_1\neq g_2$ are in $G$, there is a $\phi \in \hat G$ with $\phi (g_1) \neq \phi (g_2)$.

I have already proved that $\hat G$ is abelian and that for $\phi \in \hat G$ we have $\phi(g)$ a root of unity for every $g \in G$. I also know that $G$ is isomorphic to $\hat G$.

What I am basically proving is that each $\phi \in \hat G$ is one-to-one. Is that correct? How can I leverage the fact that $G$ and $\hat G$ are isomorphic to show that each element of $\hat G$ is in fact an isomorphism?

Comment: You're not showing that $\varphi$ is one-to-one. That's not true. For instance, the constant function at $1$ is in $\hat{G}$, but it's not 1-1. You're showing that $\hat{G}$ separates elements of $G$.

Comment: @EricAuld Okay, thank you. Do you think I should prove by contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps of a proof can be the following:

1. It suffices to show that for $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$ there exists $\phi$ such that $\phi(g)\neq 1$.
2. It suffices to prove the statement for cyclic groups due to the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups.
3. Handle the cyclic case.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why 1. is sufficient?

Comment: @user389773 $\phi(g_1)\ne \phi(g_2)\iff \phi(g_1g_2^{-1})\ne 1$.